# Create a Linux-based Docker file for .NET Framework project

Tags: c#, .net, docker, dockerfile, .net-4.8

I have an ASP.Net Framework 4.8 project. I want to create a Linux-based Docker file for this project, but I can't find a Linux-based image to use as a base image in my Docker file for .NET Framework. How can I create a Docker file for this?

Comment: You would be looking for a Mono container. https://hub.docker.com/_/mono. There is no official Microsoft .NET Framework implementation for Linux; Mono is as good as you're going to get.

Comment: Can you explain more? or give me an example? or send me a link?

Comment: I provided a link to the Docker Hub `mono` image. That's the base image you want to use for your application. That doesn't guarantee it will work, but that's your starting point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally, after a week of trying, I was able to get an answer.

We have to base the image on Nginx and install the mono on it.

1. Create a folder that contains the following:

[image]

2. Publish your asp project in the `dist` folder.
3. In the Nginx folder create a folder with the `sites-available` name.
4. In the sites-available folder create a file with the `default` name and the following codes:

```
    server {
             listen   80;
             access_log   /var/log/nginx/mono-fastcgi.log;
             root /var/www/;
             server_tokens off;
             more_clear_headers Server X-AspNet-Version;
    
             location / {
                     index index.html index.htm default.aspx Default.aspx;
                     fastcgi_index /;
                     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/mono-fastcgi.sock;
                     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
             }
     }
```

5. In the Nginx folder create a file with the `fastcgi_params` name and the following codes:

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          "";
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

6. In the pools folder create a file with the `sample.webapp` name and the following codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<apps>
    <web-application>
        <name>root</name>
        <vhost>*</vhost>
        <vport>-1</vport>
        <vpath>/</vpath>
        <path>/var/www/sample-app/</path>
    </web-application>
</apps>
```

7. `supervisord.conf` file:

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes = 50MB
nodaemon=true
user=root

[program:mono]
command=fastcgi-mono-server4 --appconfigdir=/etc/mono/pools --socket=unix --filename=/var/run/mono-fastcgi.sock --printlog --name=mono
user=root
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:nginx]
command=nginx
user=root
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

8. Finally Dickerfile:

```
FROM mono:latest

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y \
  iproute2 supervisor ca-certificates-mono fsharp mono-vbnc nuget \
  referenceassemblies-pcl mono-fastcgi-server4 nginx nginx-extras \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* \
  && echo "daemon off;" | cat - /etc/nginx/nginx.conf > temp && mv temp /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
  && sed -i -e 's/www-data/root/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY nginx/ /etc/nginx/
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY pools /etc/mono/pools
COPY dist /var/www/sample-app


EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" ]
```

Comment: Hi can you provide a sample repo? Trying to get asp.net web forms project dockerized so that external Mac OS devs can use vs code remote ssh to work on the projects… porting to .NET is on the roadmap. But Until then, development is still needed.

Answer (score 5):

.NET Framework is not cross-platform. Neither is ASP.NET itself. They do not work on Linux. So there are no Linux-based container images that would let you run .NET Framework or ASP.NET Framework.

And you can not make a custom one; .NET Framework will simply not run on Linux.

That's why Microsoft created .NET Core (and now just called .NET) and ASP.NET Core, so they would be cross-platform and you could use those on Linux, including Linux-based container images.

---

As suggested in some comments, you might be able to use mono. Mono is a (not really supported) implementation of .NET Framework that aims to work on Linux. It's not 100% bug for bug compatible with .NET Framework, so your application may or may not work with it.

---

A better, but more difficult option, would be to port your application to ASP.NET Core 6, which is supported on Linux-based containers.